# The parameter of zeros

Tags: matlab

I want to create a matrix by "zeros([numbers,3])"

```
syms x;
numbers=symsum(x,x,1,5);
zeros([numbers,3])
```

Here is the error: The size must be a number.

How to create a matrix like this "zeros([numbers,3])"

Comment: `x=5; zeros(x,3)` works fine for me. Not sure why it might help, but try clearing your workspace?

Comment: It doesn't help. My Matlab version is  R2016b. What's your version number?

Comment: it works for me on R2016b. maybe try `zeros([x,3])`

Comment: I restart my programm. But it also error.

Comment: Are you sure you are executing this and only this? Try typing it in the Matlab console and show us a small screenshot of the result.  `x=5; zeros(x,3)`

Comment: Here's the code.

syms x;
numbers=symsum(x,x,1,5);
XX=zeros([numbers,3]);

Comment: In the console, I can get the right answer. x=5; zeros(x,3)

Comment: This is because `numbers` is of sym class. Convert it to double first. i.e  use `XX=zeros(double(numbers),3);` instead

Comment: Thank you. I got it. Thanks.

Comment: This is a **complete** different question from your original one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `numbers` is of `sym` class. Convert it to [**`double`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.html) first. i.e.  use `XX=zeros(double(numbers),3);` instead.

But still there is no need to use *Symbolic Math Toolbox* here. What you're doing can be done more simply as:

```
numbers = sum(1:5);
XX = zeros(numbers,3)
```